# Barbarian's Rage + Eye of Gruumsh's Rage = Greater Rage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class, religions-and-deities, barbarian

I was wondering if a Barbarian's Rage with an Eye of Gruumsh's Rage would stack to make Greater Rage. It would make sense to me since you can have two classes with Uncanny Dodge which turns into Improved Uncanny Dodge.

Comment: As an aside... Eye of Gruumsh is an extremely dated Prestige Class. Look at Black Blood Cultist - their levels stack with Barbarian to determine the Type of Rage they get, and Number of Rages per day. Ask your DM to make a house ruling on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unfortunately Not

The extraordinary ability rage granted by the prestige class eye of Gruumsh says

> An eye of Gruumsh can fly into a rage just as a barbarian can, with all the same benefits and drawbacks (see page 25 of the *Player’s Handbook*). **An eye of Gruumsh’s class levels stack with his barbarian levels** (if any) **for determining the *number* of times per day he can use his rage ability.** Add together the character’s levels in the eye of Gruumsh and barbarian classes and **refer to** Table 3–3: The Barbarian on **page 25 of the *Player’s Handbook* to determine the *number* of rages per day.** For example, a 6th-level barbarian/2nd-level eye of Gruumsh could rage three times per day (the same as an 8th level barbarian), while a 4th-level eye of Gruumsh with no levels in barbarian could rage twice per day (the same as a 4th-level barbarian). (*CW* 33)

There's no mention of greater rage (nor of mighty rage, for that matter) in the description of the eye of Gruumsh's rage. He just rages like a normal barbarian. But he spits a lot, and everyone knows spitting is cool.

---

Only things that say that they combine for greater effects *actually* combine for greater effects. For example, a level 2 monk who gains evasion and who later becomes a level 2 rogue gains *no* benefit from having evasion twice. (That's sort of what alternative class feature are for.)